# Directory API Tokens API issue

Tags: openid, google-admin-sdk, google-openid, google-directory-api, stackexchange

I am very new to ADMIN SDK. In that there is Directory API in which i am interested in Tokens api which give me 3rd Party API access for domain user.

I am referring following link

[Directory API - Tokens](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list)

after following there instruction i just tried there `Try it now` link there i found that i have login in stackoverflow.com using google but there in list of 3rd party app i cant find stackoverflow token. Why this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm, you're testing the Directory API - Tokens and looking for your authentication for stackoverflow.com, correct?

I was able to find my token via the same process. It's listed under `"displayText": "Stack Exchange"` from what I can tell.